# make opencv2/opencv.hpp not found

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make, opencv

I am trying to build fastfusion from this repo: `https://github.com/tum-vision/fastfusion` . In the installation step, after running `CMake .`, I have to run `make`. But the `make` command fails with the following error message:

```
/home/redwanul/fastfusion/src/camerautils/camerautils.hpp:12:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
   12 | #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have searched for some solutions online. And I have found that I have the file opencv.hpp in the following directories.

`/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp`
`/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp`

So I understood that the directory opencv4 in the middle is causing problems. So I copied the folder opencv2 out of opencv4 and placed them in `/usr/include/` and `/usr/local/include`. This time the make does not shows the error. But it fails with another message:

```
/home/redwanul/fastfusion/src/auxiliary/plywriter.cpp:171:88: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘cv::DataType<cv::Vec<float, 3> >’
  171 | arityImage.rows,disparityImage.cols,cv::DataType<cv::Vec3f>::type);
      |
```

So far I am understanding that it is a opencv related error. So I think I have to install opencv a specific version. But I don't know which version or how. I tried `sudo apt-get install opencv` but the there are not package named opencv.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
sudo ln -s /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2 /usr/include/opencv2
```

with linked, in ubuntu20.04, this problem can be solved.

Comment: Or update the #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> to #include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp> in the source.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
/usr/local/include/opencv2**
```

or

```
/usr/include/opencv2**
```